# Drop rows where column contains a certain value conditional on the value of the columns on the row above

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'State': {0: "case_created", 1: "case_reopened", 2:"email_sent", 3: "case_reopened", 4: "email_sent", 5: "case_reopened", 6 : "email_sent", 7: "case_reopened"}, 
           'date': {0: '2016-10-13T14:10:41Z', 1: '2016-10-13T14:10:41Z', 2:'2016-10-13T15:26:19Z',
                    3: '2016-10-14T15:26:19Z', 4: '2016-10-15T15:26:19Z', 5: '2016-10-18T15:26:19Z',
                    6 :'2016-10-17T15:26:19Z', 7: '2016-10-13T15:26:19Z'}}, columns=['State', 'date'])
```

I am trying to calculate the times between (case_created OR case_reopened) and email_sent.

The issue is that because of a weird workflow workaround that I can't edit, sometimes there is a meaningless case_reopened timestamp after either a case_created timestamp or another case_reopened timestamp. These meaningless case_reopened timestamps can be safely discarded.

I am using shift

```
 df = df.loc[df["state"].shift() != df["state"]]
```

to get rid of the case_reopened -> case_reopened case but I'm at a loss as to how to fix the case_created -> case_reopened case. I then intend to use .diff() to calculate the time differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try to locate the rows with 'email_sent'. Then calculate the time difference between 'email_sent' and the entry after last 'email_sent'. Something as follows:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
email_sent = df['State']=='email_sent'
rs  = [0,]
for idx, v in email.iteritems():
if v:
    rs.append(idx)
    rs.append(idx+1)
df['date'][rs].diff()
```